# What is the second frechet derivative of a bilinear map?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

Calculating the first frechet derivative of a continuous bilinear map was not that hard, since you can see what the derivative is by using linearity, but what is $ f''(x,y)((a,b),(c,d))$, where f is the function that represents the bilinear map?
I want to express the second derivative in terms of the function itself

Comment: Hint: The first derivative is linear. How do you calculate the derivative of a linear function?

Comment: Ah yes, it is the function itself.

Comment: That's right. With this hint, can you calculate the second derivative?

Comment: Although, would you mind weiting down the exact answer to my question? So i can accept it?

Comment: Sure, before I dot it, can you please write the expression of the derivative, so I can see if we are talking the same language.

Comment: $f'(x,y)(k,l)=f(x,l)+f(k,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a: X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear form defined in some normed vector space $X$. As you have noted, $$a'(x,y)(u,v)=a(x,v)+a(u,y),\ \forall\ x,y,u,v\in X$$

Now, note that the above expression is the sum of two bilinear forms. If we derivate again, we will derivate $a(x,v)$ with respect to $x$ and $a(u,y)$ with respect to $y$ then, $$a''(x,y)(u,v)(z,w)=a(z,v)+a(u,w),\ \forall  u,v,z,w\in X$$